# How to parse XML to Generic List in c#

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-web-api

I'm calling WebAPI and getting an `XmlResult` so I want to read this XML result and convert to Generic List.

Here my xml format

```
<SalesList xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/"><row Total="103700.0000" Tip="Dry"/><row Total="9341.0000" Tip="Wet"/></SalesList>
```

I decode my XML and delete first node of XML and I can catch my pure XML but now when I try to fill list I cannot reach `Elements("row")`

Why? Have any idea?

Here my code

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:8095/ ");


client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
    new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/xml"));


string link = "api/Values/GeneralReport";

var response = client.GetAsync(link).Result;
string res = "";
using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
{
    Task<string> result = content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    res = result.Result;
}
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(res);
XElement firstChild = doc.Root.Elements().First();
string res1 = firstChild.ToString();
XDocument doc1 = XDocument.Parse(res1);
if (doc1.Root != null)
{
    var  listxml = (from r in doc1.Root.Elements("row")
                    select new StationInfo{
                     ItemType = (string)r.Element("Tip"),
                     Total = (decimal)r.Element("Total")}).ToList();
}
```

Comment: Double serialization. Your service returns an xml string in an xml

Comment: How to do that? Sorry i never use it? First how to convert xml string to xml @Eser

Comment: Your service -by default- returns xml or json. It seems like you create an xml from your *SalesList* manually and return that. Your service creates another xml from yours

Comment: @Eser exactly! How to do double serialization do you have any idea?

Comment: Just return *SalesList* in your server. don't create an xml.

Comment: @Eser the idea is I'm calling webservice and webservice call db execute query that query returns xml and also webservice returning xml so i can't change this algorithm i need find solution

Comment: As i said, return*SalesList* . your service will create an xml from it automatically.

Comment: It is not weird.  HTML has special character so the xml is being encoded so it can be sent over html.  Use          System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlEncode(string) and
           System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(string)

Comment: @jdweng Of course it would work but that is not the *real* problem. (BTW there is no html in this case; a pure xml)

Comment: It is the real issue. It is using HttpClient().

Comment: @jdweng No OP converts his result to xml manually and returns it. That is the real problem. Read my previous comments. If he does it that way, he will get the xml needed and never need *HtmlDecode*. Service should return `<SalesList><row Total="103700.0000" Tip="Dry"/><row Total="9341.0000" Tip="Wet"/></SalesList>` and should be coded that way.

Comment: It is the server that is adding the encoding and the server may not be the OPs code.  So the only solution would be to simply decode.

Comment: @jdweng Only if OP doesn't have access to server's code. (Since servers addr is *localhost:8095*, this is very unlikely :) )

Comment: i just changed server address that is not localhost :) but i agree with you @Eser and i need to convert SalesList to GenericList

Comment: Hi @Eser I edited question now i can catch real xml but now i cannot convert it

Comment: @saulyasar I answered it below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**a)** You don't use the xml namespace

**b)** *Tip* and *Total* are attributes, not elements

```
XNamespace ns = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/";
var listxml  = XDocument.Parse(res)
                .Descendants(ns + "row")
                .Select(x => new
                {
                    ItemType = (string)x.Attribute("Tip"),
                    Total = (string)x.Attribute("Total"),
                })
                .ToList();
```